# Cannot access Map returned by maxBy

Tags: scala, maxby

I have a `Map[String, Any]` of donuts

```
val donuts: Seq[Map[String, Any]] = Seq(Map("type" -> "plain", "price" -> 1.5), Map("type" -> "jelly", "price" -> 2.5))
```

I want to find the highest priced donut using `maxBy`.

```
val d = donuts.maxBy(donut => donut("price").toString.toDouble)
```

successfully returns `Map[String,Any] = Map(type -> "jelly", price -> 2.5)`

I can access `d("price")` to find the price of the highest priced donut. But if I try to do this in one line:

```
donuts.maxBy(donut => donut("price").toString.toDouble)("price")
```

it throws:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("price")
 required: Ordering[Double]
       (donuts.maxBy(donut => donut("price").toString.toDouble))("price")
                                                                 ^
```

What's the issue here, and how can I roll this into one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `maxBy` requires an implicit ordering parameter:

```scala
def maxBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A
```

Unfortunately you can't use apply's syntactic sugar, because whatever you pass as a second parameter list will be passed as if it were the implicit argument.
You can call apply explicitly though:

```scala
donuts.maxBy(donut => donut("price").toString.toDouble).apply("price")
```

It's not that pretty as what you're looking for but it's still a one liner.

Hope that helps :)